# GCP IAM Binding for GKE Node Pool using Workload Identity

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, binding, google-cloud-iam, workload-identity

I am scheduling jobs using Cloud Composer running tasks in Kubernetes. I have setup a new node pool in the same GKE as composer and using this to run the Kubernetes tasks. In that node pool I'm using the default service account but binding the account to the same service account as the Composer node pool, using an IAM policy binding, and enabling workload identity.

However I can see from the errors that the kubernetes service account is lacking permissions for some stuff that the composer service account does have access to. Which doesn't make sense since the kubernetes service account has an IAM Policy binding to the composer service account, so they should have exactly same permissions. But for whatever reason this is not true. Any tips on where to look are greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are you using predefinied roles or custom roles? Did you somehow change default permissions in GCP? Could you share your exact error?

Comment: When you are binding roles you are providing specific SA/predefined roles which can be found for [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-composer-roles) and [Kubernetes engine](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles). Each role has different permissions. Which roles you have used and which role are you lacking?

Comment: After looking at the service account logs I noticed that while the workload identity was enabled on the GKE it was not enabled on the nodepool, so the nodes in that pool were defaulting to the wrong service account...

Comment: So in short, you just needed to turn on `Workload Identity` on the Node Pools like mentioned in [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#migrate_applications_to)? If so, could you wrote an answer for people with similar issue?

Comment: Do you still have this issue or enabling Workload Identity solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the workload identity on the nodepool was the solution. Using terraform the solution looks like this:

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "google_container_node_pool_name" {

    workload_metadata_config {
       mode = "GKE_METADATA"
}
```